# Does a hidden creature that casts a spell reveal its position?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stealth

Does casting a spell make a creature no longer hidden?

Specifically, I'm wondering about casting a homebrew spell that, at range, heals an ally but that lacks a verbal component and has no visible effect from the caster (e.g. no sparks fly from the caster when the spell's cast nor does the caster shoot the subject with healing laser).

It seems like a hidden creature is no longer hidden if the hidden creature attacks, but what if the hidden creature casts a spell, especially a spell like this with no visible connection between caster and subject? Is the caster's position still revealed?

Comment: I'm curious--do you see any difference between your homebrew spell and any standard spell cast using the Sorceror's Subtle Spell metamagic option?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suppose there's a RAW answer and a recommended YMMV answer for this.

The insert on page 177 of the PHB details the hiding rules and the RAW for section suggest that the character would still be hidden. The character did not make noise or do any other activity that would give them away and thus would not be detected.

However, this section does give the DM latitude to deviate from it's own requirements based upon the situation. From your description of the homebrewed spell, it sounds like it's purpose was designed to allow stealthy healing on the part of the caster. You might elect to permit the opposition to note that the person they're attacking has suddenly started healing. If they've reason to believe a cleric is involved with that healing (perhaps as a result of a successful Arcana check), it could prompt an active Perception check at your discretion to locate said cleric.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard and fast rule, but there is fluff that supports it. Under page 204 of the PHB:

> ### Targets
>
> ... Unless a spell has a perceptible effect, a creature might not know it was targeted by a spell at all. An effect like crackling lightning is obvious, but a more subtle effect, such as an attempt to read a creature's thoughts typically goes unnoticed, unless a spell says otherwise.

The excerpt above seems to support that if even the target doesn't know it was targeted by a spell, onlookers may not even know as well.

If the intent of your homebrewed spell is exactly to stealth heal, then let the PC stay hidden. However, you should be asking yourself why anyone would pick Healing Word over this spell.

Comment: It should be fine. The spell is a racial bonus essentially that is specific to a homebrew race I made; it can only be used twice per long rest and it falls off heavily at later levels. 

Also, thank you for the answer! That pretty much solidifies it haha.